# CSS elements in custom css no display in frontend

Tags: html, css

It modifies the template and basically all the elements CSS that I want to change I copy code and add to the "custom css" panel and then everything works fine.

I ran into a problem with two elements that I can't change in any way. When I add code to "custom css", the old code on the frontend is still displayed.

Sample product page:
https://martfury05.magebig.com/libwx-3pcs-food-pocket-for-infant-toddlers.html

1. I need change  "add to cart" button width:
   [image]

as always I copy this code to custom css:

```
.box-tocart .actions .tocart, .box-tocart .instant-purchase {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 52px;
    min-width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: 1px solid #fcb800;
    background-color: #fcb800;
    color: #000;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

but after saving no changes.

2. Also here I have the same issue with fotorama:
   [image]

also I copy below code and paste in custom css but after save still no result on frontend.

```
.fotorama__stage__frame .fotorama__img {
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    transition-duration: .3s;
    transition-property: width,height,top,left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
}
```

Everything else works fine. Can someone tell me if I should maybe give a different css path?

Comment: why did you give me a downside? My question is relevant and in accordance with the rules.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

- you can use `>` CSS selector to give higher priority to the element. For example:

`.parent-class > .no { text-decoration:none !important; }`

- if you use `WordPress` or `Joomla` or other CMS, clean its cache.
- check your css file path
- clean your browser cache with `Ctrl+F5` or browser history
- check you write your class names correctly
- if you work with frameworks like `react`, `vue` or `angular`, it may be due to the encapsulation feature.